# ;ls bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'

Tags: bash, shell, syntax

after typing `;ls`

I got this return - `` bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;' ``

how do I fix this?

Comment: Why are you typing it? What are you going to achieve?

Comment: Did you *mean* to type `;ls`? If so, why? The easy answer is along the lines of "don't do that", but has deeper explanations, depending on your curiosity.

Comment: You could type `:;ls` instead... Or use Ksh or Zsh, which just ignore the empty command. It's somewhat interesting actually that it isn't allowed.

Comment: If you were to change that question from "_How do I fix this?_", which has the easy reply of "Don't do that", to "_Why is this?_" you'd have a really good question

Answer (score 7):

The semicolon terminates a command. Usually you don't need it, since a newline will do. But you can use to put multiple commands on one line, e.g.

```
$ echo -n "hi "; echo there
hi there
```

or maybe more usefully:

```
if [ whatever ]; then
```

Putting a semicolon at the start of a line leaves an "empty" command before it, and apparently the shell syntax forbids it. Yash gives a useful error message:

```
$ yash -c '; echo hi'
yash -c:1: syntax error: a command is missing before ‘;’
```

And Ksh and Zsh seem to just ignore the issue:

```
$ zsh -c '; echo hi'
hi
```

(But you can't use `echo foo;;` in those either, since `;;` is different from `;`, like `>` is different from `>>`. `;;` is used in `case` statements.)

The empty command doesn't do anything anyway, so you can just leave the leading semicolon out. Or switch to Zsh, I guess.

Comment: Note that `ksh93 -c 'echo test |; cat'` complains but `zsh` doesn't. In any case, I wouldn't use it anyway as `|;` may become a new operator in future versions of either  shell (like `<>;` and `>;` are already special operators in ksh93).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, or `echo test | ; cat` with the space. Or `for x in 1 2 3 4; ; do; ; echo $x; done`. In Zsh, I mean. I can see some sense in treating a semicolon a bit like a newline in that there can be many, but within a pipeline it seems a bit weird. At least it doesn't allow sprinkling `&`  around in the same way...

Comment: See also `array=( ; a ; ; ; b )`. It seems `;` is equivalent to newline in most places which is kind of consistent (though I agree a bit surprising)

Comment: The `;` in `echo one; echo two` is a control character. The `;` in `if list; then ...` is part of the `if` syntax. They are different, not equivalent.

Comment: @Isaac, not really, see also `if cmd & then...` (`if cmd |& then` in ksh). The point is that those `;`, `&`, newline, `|&`... still delimit the commands there, and the `then` keyword, like most keywords is only recognised as such in command position (though that's not the whole story as `if (true) then echo true; fi` works in most shells (and YMMV for `((1))` or `[[ x ]]` in place of `(true)`))

Comment: @Isaac, well, `if this \n that \n then whatever \n fi` also works, so it's not like the semicolon is a mandatory part of the syntax. As far as I can tell from the POSIX grammar, a top-level list of commands is defined with different rules than a compound_list you have inside `{}` or `()` or the parts of an `if`, but if there's a meaningful difference between the two in how `;`/newline work, I can't tell.

Comment: But if it's `{ echo foo; echo bar; }` vs. `if something; then`, then it's exactly the same compound_list in both.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Well, yes, there are other valid syntax(es) beside `if cmd; then`. I am well aware of them, as I hope you should be already aware. My point is somewhere else: .... The shell parser has a series of **basic** rules by which it splits a command line into words (tokens), One such rule is that a `;` is a "word delimiter". We should agree up to this point. But there are some contexts that are processed by a different parser (well, technically, the same parser bound to a different set of rules).  Cont. (1)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Cont (2) Like inside a pair of `''`, no `;` or newline or other things are no longer special (and I used `''` because it is pretty obvious what it does, but a similar argument could be built for `""`). That *different level* of parsing also apply to the section between `if` and `fi`. That's why you can not have `echo (true)` while you can (perfectly valid) do `if (true) then (echo true) fi` (note that there are no `;` and no `newlines`). So, the point is simply that the set of rules is different in basic parsing and in constructs like `if` (or `while`, `case`, `for`, etc.).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Cont (3) That is why (as basic parsing has not been suspended) **not** be a surprise that `array=( ; a ; ; ; b )` doesn't work (as `array=( a # ; ; b )` also doesn't). End (3).

Comment: @ilkkachu I am perfectly aware and clear that you are able to find a lot of corner cases to raise concern and deviate from the point raised. I won't go there. Bye.

Comment: @Isaac, FWIW, I don't think `if something; then` vs. `if something \n then` is much of a corner case, both are widely used and work. But that's neither here nor there. See you next time.

Comment: @ilkkachu We are not discussing how to replace a `;` with something else. I am saying that a `;` in basic parsing is not equivalent to a `;` inside a `if ...fi` construct. Your examples just confirm that, by the way. But never mind, running in circles is never productive for anyone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122793/discussion-between-ilkkachu-and-isaac).

Answer (score 0):

It is the same syntax error as:

```
$ ;
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

Which simply means that there should be a `cmd` before the **terminating** `;`:

```
$ ls ;
```

In such cases the `;` is a metacharacter that is defined as:

> metacharacter
> A character that, when unquoted, separates words.

Not equivalent to the `;` in the compound command:

```
if list; then list; else list; fi
```

As, in this case, it is part of the syntax of the command.